# Translations doesn't work

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm using Symfony2.6 and this is the catalogue of translation but it doesn't work

**message.en.yml**

```
#src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/message.en.yml
app:
    menu:
        home: Home
```

**message.fr.yml**

```
#src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/message.fr.yml
app:
    menu:
        home: Accueil
```

And this is the twig

```
{{ 'app.menu.home'|trans }}
```

this is the **output**

```
APP.MENU.HOME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation namespace is not correct (the final *s* of message is missing), the files should be named:

```
#src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
#src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.fr.yml
```

Or call the trans helper with the `message` namespace:

```
{{ 'app.menu.home'|trans({},'message') }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your translator file name might be messages.fr.yml you named it message.fr.yml
the default translation domain is messges if you use any other translator file name , in your twig file you can translate in 2 way:

1. {% trans_default_domain "translator-file-name"%} in first line of twig
   note : if your translator file name is like this : mytrans.fa.yml your domain must set in this way

> {% trans_default_domain "mytrans"%}

2. {{ "app.menu.home"|trans({},"mytrans")}}

Answer (score 0):

What you did seems correct so there's probably a typo somewhere. Check carefully the YML file syntax and spaces, it's easy to mess it up.